# Karaf / Maven missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta)

Tags: hazelcast, apache-karaf, karaf, hazelcast-imap

I am running a simple hazelcast application in karaf 4.0.3 by following the below link,

https://darylmathison.com/2014/04/01/beginners-guide-to-hazelcast-part-1/

I am able to compile the code susses fully but while starting the bundle i am getting the below error like,

```
2016-05-05 17:57:46,067 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | ShellUtil                        | 44 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.0.3 | Exception caught while executing command
org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
Error starting bundle137: Unable to resolve HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313): missing requirement [HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta) Unresolved requirements: [[HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta)]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:61)
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:69)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.execute(BundlesCommand.java:54)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:270)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.3]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error starting bundle137: Unable to resolve HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313): missing requirement [HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta) Unresolved requirements: [[HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta)]
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:66)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
... 12 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313): missing requirement [HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta) Unresolved requirements: [[HazelcastArtifact [137](R 137.1313)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta)]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:38)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:64)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.3]
... 12 more
```

I am getting this missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta) all the time. I have also tried adding below lines in pom.xml file,

```
<Import-Package>
org.osgi.framework,
osgi.wiring.package,
android.dalvik,
javax.annotation,version=1.6.0,
javax.annotation.processing,version=1.6.0
</Import-Package>
```

but didn't help much. Please help me resolving this missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta) error while starting the bundle.

Comment: Hi, I'm also getting the same error. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

First check if there is also a bundle available that actually exports this package in that version.
If this isn't true, install the required bundle to satisfy this dependency.